# How is client-side rendering done in Eclipse RAP?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, eclipse-rap, servlet-container

I read about [Eclipse RAP](http://www.eclipse.org/rap/) and understood what a *"servlet container"* is: some kind of a java applet on a server instead of a client.

I don't understand how RAP applications are rendered on browsers... are they pure Javascript, HTML5, Java applets, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Eclipse RAP wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP):

> The RAP project aims to enable developers to build rich, Ajax-enabled
>   Web applications by using the Eclipse development model, plug-ins and
>   a Java-only API.

So you write your code in Java, and the client UI is rendered using AJAX (read: Javascript.)

This implies [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) is used to update the client interface. Some research indicates that RAP uses a [legacy version](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/654246/) of the [Qooxdoo js library](http://qooxdoo.org/), and [they don't plan on upgrading](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=646965) because they want to maintain a lightweight client.

The developer has control over HTML / CSS content.

Also, the **servlet container** is a dispatcher that handles URL requests and interacts with your servlets. It's responsible for *"managing the life-cycle of servlets, mapping a URL to a particular servlet, and ensuring that the URL requester has the correct access rights."* [ [1](http://angelozerr.wordpress.com/2011/05/20/rap_step4/), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) ]